# How to force user to draw signature first time and then adopt in Docusign?

Tags: docusignapi

with signInEachLocation set to TRUE user has to draw signature every time and if it is set to FALSE docusign autocreates signature for user to adopt. I want user not to adopt the autocreated signature by docusign, instead force user to draw signature for the first time and then adopt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a setting in Signature Adoption Configuration where you can configure where signer should adopt or draw the signature first time. You can find more details [here](https://www.docusign.com/supportdocs/ndse-admin-guide/Content/signature-adopt-config.htm). By default, DS gives `Adopt a Signature` on a website and `Draw a Signature` on Mobile. But you can modify those settings in your Admin settings as explained in the [Support Docs](https://www.docusign.com/supportdocs/ndse-admin-guide/Content/signature-adopt-config.htm)